# Can't visualize web service of wireless cameras using Chromium

Tags: chromium, webcam

When I write the IP address of my camera using Chromium I can't visualize them, it's because the cameras need ActiveX activated on IE.

How can I see ActiveX content in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to use ActiveX in Ubuntu, the short answer is no. Wine browser seems to use Gecko, and IEs4Linux has been abandoned (and I'm not sure ActiveX even worked with that). Google Chrome only supports ActiveX in Chrome browser in South Korea in windows, because the major South Korean banks have been running their web apps with ActiveX for a long time. Apparently it's possible to run Chrome for windows in Wine, but even then if you get Google's patched Chrome for the South Korean market, I don't think it would be available in any language other than Korean. If your computer can handle it, I'd recommend running XP in VirtualBox, otherwise you may want to dual-boot and grab the photos from your cameras that way and store them on a shared partition. It might be less of a hassle to just use a memory card reader, I certainly hope you're not relying on this ActiveX feature for productivity.